# css cache google chrome

Tags: css, caching, google-chrome

I'm having problems with cache, I think.
I have a website in Joomla, and I have some .css (layout.css, position.css, .... ) and I have at home of the website, 3 buttons, I tested in localhost, and when I see the home well, I upload everything to production, to my server.
Now, I just edited some styles of these buttons, for example, the width, in order to see them better...**but I'm having a problem with the cache, because sometimes I see them with new changes, but other times I see with the old styles.....I realized that this happens especially with chrome**
Could you help me, please?
Best regards, Daniel

Comment: On SuperUser: [How can I do a Cache Refresh in Google Chrome?](http://superuser.com/questions/220179/how-can-i-do-a-cache-refresh-in-google-chrome)

Comment: do this ctrl + F5 on windows, Cmd+shift+r on Mac :D

Comment: But if I do, I'll see well...but other people that visit my website in their computers? what happen? Thanks very much friends I'm in windows xp and I refresh the website directly with F5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force the browser to use the latest stylesheet. Read more here:
http://www.impressivewebs.com/force-browser-newest-stylesheet/

I hope that helps.

Comment: I did this, and it solved my problem with cache. Thanks friend.

Comment: Will this method always work? I have tried this and noticed one time it didn't seem to work right away.

Answer (score 2):

Try delete cache data when new version is done, see [hint](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95582).
In FF you can delete cache data by use a combination of keys `Ctrl+F5`.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome is an awesome browser but the cache is a bit of pain, I use the incognito mode as this also switches off the cache from my experience.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need one solution that solves the problem in order to all the users see the website well, that is, with the latest css included, not the oldest. The link added by Christofer Vilander solved the problem. Regards, Daniel